# ERROR: "acmod.c", line 79: Folder '/...' does not contain acoustic model definition 'mdef' - cmusphinx - TLSphinx

Tags: ios, swift, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

How do I fix this?

I am trying this [wrapper to pocketsphinx](https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx) with their example code[example code](https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx#processing-an-audio-file).

Here is that code in my Xcode iOS project in Swift:

```
let hmm = "/Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us" // Path to the acustic model
let lm = "/Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/basic-lm/6844.lm" // Path to the languaje model
let dict = "/Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict" // Path to the languaje dictionary

if let config = Config(args: ("-hmm", hmm), ("-lm", lm), ("-dict", dict)) {
    if let decoder: TLSphinx.Decoder = TLSphinx.Decoder(config:config) {

        let audioFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio16000", ofType: "mp3")! // Path to an audio file

        do {
            try decoder.decodeSpeech(atPath: audioFile) {

                if let hyp: Hypothesis = $0 {
                    // Print the decoder text and score
                    print("Text: \(hyp.text) - Score: \(hyp.score)")
                } else {
                    // Can't decode any speech because of an error
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    } else {
        // Handle Decoder() fail
    }
} else {
    // Handle Config() fail
}
```

I get the following error after making sure that the mdef file is where my code says it is:

(The significant error message is at the very end.)

```
Current configuration: [NAME]           [DEFLT]     [VALUE]
-agc            none        none
-agcthresh      2.0     2.000000e+00
-allphone               
-allphone_ci        no      no
-alpha          0.97        9.700000e-01
-ascale         20.0        2.000000e+01
-aw         1       1
-backtrace      no      no
-beam           1e-48       1.000000e-48
-bestpath       yes     yes
-bestpathlw     9.5     9.500000e+00
-ceplen         13      13
-cmn            live        live
-cmninit        40,3,-1     40,3,-1
-compallsen     no      no
-debug                  0
-dict                   /Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
-dictcase       no      no
-dither         no      no
-doublebw       no      no
-ds         1       1
-fdict                  
-feat           1s_c_d_dd   1s_c_d_dd
-featparams             
-fillprob       1e-8        1.000000e-08
-frate          100     100
-fsg                    
-fsgusealtpron      yes     yes
-fsgusefiller       yes     yes
-fwdflat        yes     yes
-fwdflatbeam        1e-64       1.000000e-64
-fwdflatefwid       4       4
-fwdflatlw      8.5     8.500000e+00
-fwdflatsfwin       25      25
-fwdflatwbeam       7e-29       7.000000e-29
-fwdtree        yes     yes
-hmm                    /Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/
-input_endian       little      little
-jsgf                   
-keyphrase              
-kws                    
-kws_delay      10      10
-kws_plp        1e-1        1.000000e-01
-kws_threshold      1       1.000000e+00
-latsize        5000        5000
-lda                    
-ldadim         0       0
-lifter         0       0
-lm                 /Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/basic-lm/6844.lm
-lmctl                  
-lmname                 
-logbase        1.0001      1.000100e+00
-logfn                  
-logspec        no      no
-lowerf         133.33334   1.333333e+02
-lpbeam         1e-40       1.000000e-40
-lponlybeam     7e-29       7.000000e-29
-lw         6.5     6.500000e+00
-maxhmmpf       30000       30000
-maxwpf         -1      -1
-mdef                   
-mean                   
-mfclogdir              
-min_endfr      0       0
-mixw                   
-mixwfloor      0.0000001   1.000000e-07
-mllr                   
-mmap           yes     yes
-ncep           13      13
-nfft           512     512
-nfilt          40      40
-nwpen          1.0     1.000000e+00
-pbeam          1e-48       1.000000e-48
-pip            1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_beam        1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pbeam       1e-10       1.000000e-10
-pl_pip         1.0     1.000000e+00
-pl_weight      3.0     3.000000e+00
-pl_window      5       5
-rawlogdir              
-remove_dc      no      no
-remove_noise       yes     yes
-remove_silence     yes     yes
-round_filters      yes     yes
-samprate       16000       1.600000e+04
-seed           -1      -1
-sendump                
-senlogdir              
-senmgau                
-silprob        0.005       5.000000e-03
-smoothspec     no      no
-svspec                 
-tmat                   
-tmatfloor      0.0001      1.000000e-04
-topn           4       4
-topn_beam      0       0
-toprule                
-transform      legacy      legacy
-unit_area      yes     yes
-upperf         6855.4976   6.855498e+03
-uw         1.0     1.000000e+00
-vad_postspeech     50      50
-vad_prespeech      20      20
-vad_startspeech    10      10
-vad_threshold      2.0     2.000000e+00
-var                    
-varfloor       0.0001      1.000000e-04
-varnorm        no      no
-verbose        no      no
-warp_params                
-warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam          7e-29       7.000000e-29
-wip            0.65        6.500000e-01
-wlen           0.025625    2.562500e-02

INFO: feat.c(715): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='live', VARNORM='no', AGC='none' ERROR: "acmod.c", line 79: Folder '/Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/' does not contain acoustic model definition 'mdef'
```

I have looked at line 79 in acmod.c. It says:

```
                    "definition 'mdef'\n", hmmdir);
```

It's in the segment of acmod.c that says:

```
    /* Read model definition. */
    if ((mdeffn = cmd_ln_str_r(acmod->config, "_mdef")) == NULL) {
        if ((hmmdir = cmd_ln_str_r(acmod->config, "-hmm")) == NULL)
            E_ERROR("Acoustic model definition is not specified either "
                    "with -mdef option or with -hmm\n");
        else
            E_ERROR("Folder '%s' does not contain acoustic model "
                    "definition 'mdef'\n", hmmdir);

        return -1;
    }
```

Here is [acmod.c in its entirety](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/6061af42f532baebb2a9cde66f05666845e3025b/src/libpocketsphinx/acmod.c).

Comment: Perhaps you should show us the contents of `model/en-us/en-us` directory.

Comment: @Mazyod Here is a link to an image of the contents of that directory showing in Finder on my Mac mini: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AooJiM96YK-_8DoywkWJDmgSLBXS

Comment: there is a chance that the directory shown in the image is in a different path than the directory requested by the output shown. I say this because I've seen this error many times, and usually it's when I have misplaced my project files.

Comment: to do a quick check do this in terminal: `ls /Users/shinehah/Documents/cmusphinx/TLSphinx-master-02/Sphinx/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/en-us/`

Comment: I ran that ls command in terminal. It checks out. The correct files are displayed.

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot that you’re running on iOS simulator. It actually won’t be able to load files on your disk, as the simulator has its own Filesystem. Hmm, lm, dict should all be loaded from the main bundle, same way you’re doing with the mp3.

Comment: @Mazyod Do you think this problem will not be there if I use an actual device?

Comment: No, it won’t be resolved. You must copy all required resources and ship it with the IPA

Comment: @Mazyod What does IPA stand for? I think I know what you mean. I need to copy those files into the Xcode project and get the paths to them using the Bundle class. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, IPA is the built application artifact